# Summarize a list of Haskell records

Tags: haskell, lenses

Let's say I have a list of records, and I want to summarize it by taking the median. More concretely, say I have

```
data Location = Location { x :: Double, y :: Double }
```

I have a list of measurements, and I want to summarize it into a median `Location`, so something like:

```
Location (median (map x measurements)) (median (map y measurements))
```

That is fine, but what if I have something more nested, such as:

```
data CampusLocation = CampusLocation { firstBuilding :: Location
                                      ,secondBuilding :: Location }
```

I have a list of `CampusLocation`s and I want a summary `CampusLocation`, where the median is applied recursively to all fields.

What is the cleanest way to do this in Haskell? Lenses? Uniplate?

Edit: Bonus:

What if instead of a record containing fields we want to summarize, we had an implicit list instead? For example:

```
data ComplexCampus = ComplexCampus { buildings :: [Location] }
```

How can we summarize a `[ComplexCampus]` into a `ComplexCampus`, assuming that each of the `buildings` is the same length?

Comment: I am suddenly imagining this kind of thing would fit a "dual" of lens traversals: "applicals" with type `forall f. Traversable f => (f a -> b) -> (f s -> t)`. No idea if anyone thought of those yet.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I'm not sure whether this is relevant here, but there is a "cotraverse" in [distributive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.4.4/docs/Data-Distributive.html).

Comment: @AndrásKovács That does look relevant and I should have remembered that.  By Kmett's usual naming scheme what I suggested (except with `Functor`, which he says is enough) would be a "cotraversal" then.  To make the types in the question actually `distributive`, they would need to change `Double` into a type parameter.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view Lenses operate fairly well on general Profunctor transformers `Profunctor p => p a b -> p s t` where we recover the Van Laarhoven formulation by demanding that p is a "representable" Profunctor. So, you're asking for a ["corepresentable" Profunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-Profunctor-Rep.html#t:Corepresentable) in your lens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an implementation of `summarize :: [ComplexCampus] -> ComplexCampus` that uses Lenses w/ Uniplate (as you mentioned) to summarize a list of ComplexCampus a single ComplexCampus.

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell,DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Lens
import Data.Data.Lens
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data
import Data.List(transpose,genericLength)
data Location = Location { _x :: Double, _y :: Double } deriving(Show,Typeable,Data)


data CampusLocation =  CampusLocation { _firstBuilding :: Location, _firsecondBuilding :: Location }deriving(Show,Typeable,Data)
data ComplexCampus = ComplexCampus { _buildings :: [Location] } deriving(Show,Typeable,Data)


makeLenses ''Location
makeLenses ''CampusLocation
makeLenses ''ComplexCampus

l1 = Location 1 10
l2 = Location 2 20
l3 = Location 3 30


c1 = CampusLocation l1 l2
c2 = CampusLocation l2 l3
c3 = CampusLocation l1 l3
campusLocs = [c1,c2,c3]


c1' = ComplexCampus [l1, l2]
c2' = ComplexCampus [l2, l3]
c3' = ComplexCampus [l1, l3]
campusLocs' = [c1',c2',c3']


average l = (sum l) / (genericLength l)

-- returns average location for a list of locations
averageLoc locs = Location {
             _x = average $ locs ^.. biplate . x,
             _y = average $ locs ^.. biplate . y
             }


summarize :: [ComplexCampus] -> ComplexCampus
summarize ccs = ComplexCampus $ ccs ^.. biplate . buildings ^.. folding transpose . to averageLoc
```

Using biplate here is likely overkill, but regardless in `averageLoc` we use `biplate` on the list of locations to get all `x` fields and all `y` fields. If you wanted to summarize a `ComplexCampus` into a single `Location` we could use `biplate` to extract all `x` values and all `y` values from the top level `ComplexBuilding`.

For example:

`campusLocs' ^.. biplate . x` gives us all x values and`campusLocs' ^.. biplate . y` gives us all y values

Likewise, to get all locations, we could just do:

`(campusLocs' ^.. biplate) ::[Location]`

Or, if we wanted every Double:
`(campusLocs' ^.. biplate) ::[Double]`

Comment: Why not just `summarize = ComplexCampus . map averageLoc . transpose . map _buildings`? I don't see essential use for lens/biplate here.

Comment: `sum xs / genericLength xs` traverses xs twice and takes O(n) space. You want to use a strict fold that accumulates the sum and counts as it goes so you can traverse once in constant space. For more info, check out http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Anyway, the original question asks for median, not average, which I think basically rules out making it constant space.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Good point, but someone is going to teach someone else an average function, I'd prefer they didn't use `sum xs / genericLength xs`.

Comment: `foldl` now supports lenses/traversals, so you can now write: `let average = liftA2 (/) sum genericLength in Location <$> pretraverse x average <*> pretraverse y average :: Fold Location Location` to traverse the list just once, strictly, and in constant space

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I was confused there until I googled, so I should point out you are talking about your [foldl package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) based on the ideas in the blog post ReinHenrichs linked.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez +1, foldl should always come with a link that it's a hackage library :)

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez BTW I think your `pretraverse` is too strictly typed. Without a type signature, it should be able to work with (unfortunate name clash there) [`Control.Lens.Fold.Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yeah, I think you're right.  I will try to just go with the more general type, then.